# ASP.NET MVC Model Patterns: What works best?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I've done a couple of projects in ASP.NET MVC and there is a topic that I haven't really seen covered anywhere. I wanted to get some other peoples' opinions on this.

What are some best practices for designing models? I've taken two approaches in the past: Should models represent distinct entities, or should you have domain specific (sub-domain specific? view specific?) models? The difference really being models representing distinct entities are used in more than one view where as the domain specific models are tied to specific views.

Consider the following: I have a User entity in my application. Should I have a single UserModel that I use in the Register view, the Show view, the Index view, etc., or would it be preferred to have a RegisterUserModel, a ShowUserModel, a ListUserModel, etc.?

I've used both patterns before. The up side of the domain specific models is that any validation logic applied via attributes can be different between views. The down side is you violate DRY and your models get pretty hairy -- even if you separate them in to namespaces. Conversely, using the single model-to-entity pattern leads to overly generic validation data (usually with regard to error messages) but you have a nice, tight model layer and converting between models and entities is a lot easier (less code).

What approach does SO prefer? Or is there an approach that I'm not even considering?

Comment: I'm sure you're going to get answers from people who prefer both ways. It's pretty subjective.

Comment: Isn't that the fun of having a discussion?

Answer (score 4):

I like to create my data models and then create specific view models as I need them.

[The Case for ViewModel](https://web.archive.org/web/20120720233123/http://www.nikhilk.net:80/Why-ViewModel.aspx)

[The ViewModel Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dphill/the-viewmodel-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

When I think of domain models, I think about business logic as well. I try to keep the M in MVC to refer to the models that assist in the presentation aspect of the application, and not the entities (domain objects) that represent my real-world objects.

Comment: I kind of subscribe to this as well and I think that a lot of other frameworks miss this -- i.e. RoR.

Answer (score 1):

Model and View shuld be a pair. Building huge Model classes and huge Views is not good idea. In my opinion in your view-Model you should represent only needed part of your business logic. For example. When you'r creating Registration form make your Model and View that simple as it can be possible - Create `RegisterUserModel.cs` and `RegisterUserView.aspx`. Do not pass there whole User object. Make it light, don't break Single Responibility Principle.